# How can I create a bot which replies something to random messages. im using an event handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i want my bot on discord to have custom replies for example:

`user: Hi`

`bot: Hello`

`user: ping`

`bot: pong`

I want to make my bot do this but i'm using an event handler for all the commands i'm using and I don't want to use `If(message.content ==... message.channel.send ".."` in the messagecreate.js or the index.js file because I'm planning to use multiple messages like so and I'd like my code to be relatively clean and organized

so if there is any way I can move the 'if' statements to another `messagereplies.js` file and run it from there, please let me know

This is my messagecreat.js file

```js
require('dotenv').config();
    module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
        const prefix = (process.env.PREFIX);
    
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
    
        if (command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
```

and this is my event handler

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) => {
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

        for (const file of event_files) {
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client))
        }
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

Basically I just want a block in the messagecreate.js file or event_handler.js file that executes another file in another folder if a message is sent

Comment: You could just create another event file called `messageCreate.messagereplies.js`, and put your messageCreate handler for your custom replies in there. Your event handler should be able to handle that already. You should probably also look into [`switch` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), they reduce redundancy by not needing to have a bunch of `message.content == x` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json file call it whatever and inside of it put your trigger phrase and its response like so, for this example, I'm calling it catchPhrase.json

```json
{
    "hi": "hello",
    "ping": "pong",
    "here": "there",
    "nowhere": "everywhere",
    "master": "slave",
    "mac": "pc"
}
```

Then in your event listener you only need one if statement

```js
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = (process.env.PREFIX);
    const catchPhrase = require('path/to/catchPhrase.json')
    if (catchPhrase[message.content]) return message.reply(`${catchPhrase[message.content]}`)
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
    
    if (command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

[image: Demo]